# Knockout.js posting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

What is the simplest method of posting a form to the server when clicking the submit button using knockout.js?

This is what I have currently but it is not posting. What is broken with my saveForm function?

```
// Here's my data model with save option
var self = this;
var viewModel;
$.getJSON('@Url.Content("~/api/myData")', function (data) {
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    self.save = function (form) {
        alert("Could now transmit to server");
    };

    viewModel.saveForm = function () {
        var jsonData = ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Content("~/api/myData")',
            data: jsonData
        });
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

Comment: Where are you invoking the saveForm method? The fact that you are using a button of type "submit" is also a problem. You don't want to do a standard form POST. It should be a "button" type with a data-bind of the click to the saveForm function.

Comment: What type of button type should I use?

Comment: Rich told you: `<button>Submit</button>`

Comment: I see: <button data-bind="submit: saveForm">Submit</button>

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know about the submit binding. I was assuming a "click" button binding. But it also looks like there is a submit binding, though it would belong on the form, not the button, and the button would remain of type "submit"

Comment: Every time I add either a submit binding to the form or a click binding to the button, the .js breaks. The debugger is telling me saveForm is not defined but I am not sure what needs to be defined for saveForm?

Answer (score 1):

probably worth putting the line

```
debugger;
```

before

```
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

and checking what happens to viewModel in firebug.   "viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);" will replace everything in viewModel with the json you are loading. This includeds your function saveForm

Comment: That got me a little further. I now see an error that saveForm is not defined but I am not sure what needs to be defined for saveForm?

Comment: @simple .as i mentioned in the answer. when you do viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data)  your viewmodel is being destroyed along with saveform.  $.getJSON happens asynchronously so what is happening is that you define the viewmodel code, then when the getjson finisheds, you are clearing it away. move the saveform outside the getjson code block, then comment out the getjson code, then the saveform will work.  the getjson code is the problem